# Error while deploying the solr service in tomcat

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, solr, lucene

I am new to `tomcat` and `solr` . So `solr` is running on the tomcat server . When I run the tomcat using the `sudo service tomcat7 start` then it works perfectly,gets deployed properly. But when I am doing it from `eclipse` using the `tomcat7:run` goal then it is giving me some problems like -

```
ERROR UpdateLog:120 - Failure to open existing log file (non fatal) /opt/solr-tomcat/solr/collection1/data/tlog/tlog.0000000000000000146:org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /opt/solr-tomcat/solr/collection1/data/tlog/tlog.0000000000000000146 (Permission denied)
```

`ERROR UpdateLog:1441 - Error deleting file: /opt/solr-tomcat/solr/collection1/data/tlog/tlog.0000000000000000146`
2017-07-06 14:39:05 `ERROR UpdateLog:120 - Failure to open existing log file (non fatal) /opt/solr-tomcat/solr/collection1/data/tlog/tlog.0000000000000000147:org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /opt/solr-tomcat/solr/collection1/data/tlog/tlog.0000000000000000147 (Permission denied)`

```
Caused by: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Error opening new searcher
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /opt/solr-tomcat/solr/collection1/data/index/write.lock (Permission denied)
```

I changed the permission of that folder as well now it is a `tomcat7`.
   In the  solr-tomcat folder.

```
  drwxr-xr-x 3 tomcat7 tomcat7 4096 Jul  6 14:11 solr/
    -rw-r--r-- 1 tomcat7 tomcat7 2118 Jul  6 14:11 solr.xml
```

Can any one please help me with this ?

Comment: i suggest you use jetty , it is a good choice !

Answer (score 1):

Solr 5.0+ Support for deploying Solr into servers (like tomcat )no longer supported.

Solr should be a standalone server, follow these [steps](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Installing+Solr)